# Migrate a Windows 7 HDD to a SSD

Tags: ssd

I'm buying a SSD with the same capacity as a HDD already have installed. My idea is to CloneZilla the HDD into a image, then put that image on the SSD.

Once I do that, do I have to reconfigure Windows 7 so it recognizes it as an SSD, and properly preserve it without giving it more wear and tear that it is suppose to?

Comment: [You shouldn't have to do anything special really](http://www.howtogeek.com/97242/how-to-migrate-windows-7-to-a-solid-state-drive/)

Comment: Just in case Windows doesn't do it automatically, run Windows Experience Index benchmark after migration. If your hard drive scores over 6.5, which it will, Windows will disable Superfetch for you. That's the only thing i can think of that might need your manual intervention. Enjoy your new ssd!

Comment: @Ramhound That is a lot setting up to do. With alignment and stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Most SSD's come with software made specifically for your use case. I can say from experience that Samsung and Intel software provided with their SSD's work amazingly well and require no further setup or config at all.

If you're not buying one of those brands that DONT supply the software there are a myriad of great cloning tools including CloneZilla as you've mentioned. These will all do the trick just fine.

That said, it wouldn't hurt to ensure that your motherboard (or SATA card if you're using a dedicated one) drivers are fully up to date as well as Windows updates.

If you want to test that the SSD is working and at what speed, [CrystalDiskMark](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html) is a popular tool for such.

So in short, no there is no further config required once cloned